# Is there an if Firefox that is similar to the if IE hack

Tags: firefox, cross-browser

As I have been learning, I have developed a bad habit of only doing things in chrome. More recently I have started looking at stuff I make in other browsers; it sucks. I have noticed that the positioning in firefox is a little different, safari is basically the same, and IE is a hot mess. For now I am just going to focus on getting things to work correctly in firefox. Is there a sort of `if Firefox` conditional statement?

Comment: a word of advice: don't try to patch up the glitches; investigate what's causing them. IE excluded, you should never need browser-specific code these days. (and even for IE, it's less of an issue than it used to be now that IE6 is dead and buried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to *IE Conditional Comments* in Mozilla based browsers like Firefox.

Depending on your server-side platform (if any), you could elect to sniff the browser type and conditionally include different style-sheets.  Of course, you want to avoid this as much as possible. Usually by fixing things to work consistently across all browsers, you end up with better, more robust, site that will probably save you time in the long run.

Regarding CSS differences, you might consider starting with a reset CSS, such as the one suggested in Joe's answer, to provide a uniform baseline.

Regarding standardization of HTML and other features between the browsers, you might want to check out [modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I find this script will solve a lot of quirks (minus IE of course) [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to make chrome and firefox render the same. I am using linux so I have not even tried testing in safari and ie yet though.